# lldb set exception breakpoint with "-w"

Tags: debugging, lldb

I read the document of `help breakpoint set` which tells me that I can use `breakpoint set -w <boolean>` to set a breakpoint where an exception throws.

what confused me is that I can't set the boolean value.
I've tried `breakpoint set -w true` and `breakpoint set -w 1` and `breakpoint set -w yes`, but they all make no sense, lldb always tells me that `error: invalid combination of options for the given command`.

so, my question is: how to enable a exception breakpoint using `breakpoint set -w <boolean>` command?

yes, I know Xcode can easily do this without any typing, but I want to know how to enable it in command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the "Command Options usage" part of the `help breakpoint set` output, you'll see that the -w and -h options are only allowed in conjunction with with the -E option.  That's because they just modify the language specific exception breakpoint set with the -E option.  Note also, `-w true` is the default, so you only need to specify this option if you want to NOT break on exception throws for your given language exception.  In general, if you want to break for instance on C++ exception throws you can say:

```
(lldb) break set -E c++
```

though you could also say

```
(lldb) break set -E c++ -w true -h false
```

to get the same effect.